# How to create a UV layout image?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I want to export my texture and i want to display on it also the UV layout
(Like on this image ) :
[image]

How can i do that ? I can do this in blender or this can be done only in an image editor software ?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the UV map

[image]

and then overlay it onto the image texture in an image editor

Comment: I did that but the exported Uv Layout is not thick enough. When i put it over the  texture i almost  cant see it.

Comment: Look at the export options. You can increase the transparency which I believe is around 25% (not at my computer)

Comment: I already tweeked that valeu.Is not enough even if i decrease the transparency to 0